# Terminal operator for Kotlin sequence that discard the output?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I'm operating on very large Kotlin sequence, I'm executing my logic on every step of the sequence and I never need to keep the whole sequence in memory.

Currently my code looks like this

```
hugeSequence
    .filter { ... } 
    .map {...... }
    .onEach {
        callExpensiveOperation(it)
    }
    .toList()  <- this feels wrong
```

The `toList()` at the bottom is the `terminal` operator, but I'm worried that Kotlin may try to create a huge list in memory, before realising that I'm not even assign the result value of that operation.

Is there any other terminal operator I can use just to trigger the sequence to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `forEach` instead of `onEach`. It is the terminal equivalent of `onEach`.

```
hugeSequence
    .filter { ... } 
    .map {...... }
    .forEach {
        callExpensiveOperation(it)
    }
```